# How do I pass two results from separate AsyncTask inner classes to the same method in the main activity?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, inner-classes

I hope I explained this issue correctly in the title. I have some inner classes that extend AsyncTask to read some JSON data and parse it. I have two separate ones for each search query the user makes. Once I have the two separate results I want to do stuff with them in the same method. My thought was to use a variable argument method and in the onPostExecute of each individual AsyncTask send the result to that method. Not sure if this is the right way to go about it as the app is crashing on search. I hope this makes sense. Thanks for any help. Ill try to make this clearer if need be.

```
package com.tot.tipofthetongue;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Main extends Activity {
    EditText searchOne;
    EditText searchTwo;
    Button findItems;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.totlayout);

        //set the UI elements
        searchOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchOne);
        searchTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchTwo);
        findItems = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findItems);

    }
    public void displayResults(View view){
        //do something in response to button


        //make person search url1
        final StringBuilder personSearchURLOne = new StringBuilder(getName.getName1(searchOne)); 
        final String searchURLOne = personSearchURLOne.toString();
        Log.d("searchurlone", searchURLOne.toString());

        //make person search url2
        final StringBuilder personSearchURLTwo = new StringBuilder(getName.getName2(searchTwo));
        final String searchURLTwo = personSearchURLTwo.toString();
        Log.d("searchurltwo", searchURLTwo.toString());
        new getIdOne().execute(searchURLOne);
        new getIdTwo().execute(searchURLTwo);



    }
    public void myFirstID(String idOne){
        final StringBuilder creditURLOne = new StringBuilder(buildCreditURL.getCreditURLOne(idOne));
        String creditOne = creditURLOne.toString();
        Log.d("idString", creditOne.toString());
        new getFirstTitle().execute(creditOne);
    }

    public void mySecondID(String idTwo){
        final StringBuilder creditURLTwo = new StringBuilder(buildCreditURL.getCreditURLTwo(idTwo));
        String creditTwo = creditURLTwo.toString();

        new getSecondTitle().execute(creditTwo);
    }

    public class getIdOne extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String TAG_ID = "id";
            String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
            String personOne = null;
            String firstID = null;
            JSONArray results = null;
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jSon = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(personOne);

            try{
                results = jSon.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

                for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
                    firstID = r.getString(TAG_ID);

                }

            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("Error", e.toString());
            }
            return firstID;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            //make credit search url1
            myFirstID(result);

    }
    }

    public class getIdTwo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String TAG_ID = "id";
            String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
            String personTwo = null;
            String secondID = null;
            JSONArray results = null;
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jSon = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(personTwo);

            try{
                results = jSon.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

                for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
                    secondID = r.getString(TAG_ID);
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("Error", e.toString());
            }
            return secondID;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            //make credit search url1
            mySecondID(result);

        }

    }
    public class getFirstTitle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>>{

        String TAG_CAST = "cast";
        String TAG_TITLE = "title";

        ArrayList<String> firstCast = new ArrayList<String>();
        String title = null;
        JSONArray castArray;
        String creditURLOne = null;
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jSon = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(creditURLOne);

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... creditOne) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            creditURLOne = creditOne.toString();
            return getFirstJSONTitle(creditURLOne);
        }
        final ArrayList<String> getFirstJSONTitle(String creditURLOne){
            Log.d("crediturl in title method has", castArray.toString());
            try{
                castArray = jSon.getJSONArray(TAG_CAST);
                for(int i=0; i<castArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject f = castArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    title = f.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    firstCast.add(title);
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                return null;
            }
            return firstCast;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result){
            getFirstCast(firstCast);
        }

    }

    public class getSecondTitle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>>{
        String TAG_CAST = "cast";
        String TAG_TITLE = "title";

        ArrayList<String> secondCast = new ArrayList<String>();
        String title = null;
        JSONArray castArray;
        String creditURLTwo = null;
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jSon = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(creditURLTwo);

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... creditTwo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            creditURLTwo = creditTwo.toString();
            return getSecondJSONTitle(creditURLTwo);
        }
        final ArrayList<String> getSecondJSONTitle(String creditURLTwo){
            Log.d("crediturl in title method has", castArray.toString());
            try{
                castArray = jSon.getJSONArray(TAG_CAST);
                for(int i=0; i<castArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject f = castArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    title = f.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    secondCast.add(title);
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                return null;
            }
            return secondCast;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result){
            getSecondCast(secondCast);
        }

    }
    public static ArrayList<String> getFirstCast(ArrayList<String> firstCast){
        return firstCast;
    }


    public static ArrayList<String> getSecondCast(ArrayList<String> secondCast){
        return secondCast;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getItems(ArrayList<String> firstCast, ArrayList<String> secondCast){
        if(firstCast.size() < secondCast.size()){
            firstCast.retainAll(secondCast);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayResultsActivity.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("myItems", firstCast);
            startActivity(intent);
            return null;
        }
        else{
            secondCast.retainAll(firstCast);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayResultsActivity.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("myItems", firstCast);
            startActivity(intent);
            return null;
        }


    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.totlayout, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here are my logcat errors

```
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:353)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:725)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.tot.tipofthetongue.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:34)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.tot.tipofthetongue.Main$getIdOne.doInBackground(Main.java:78)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.tot.tipofthetongue.Main$getIdOne.doInBackground(Main.java:1)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-17 01:07:36.754: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  ... 4 more
06-17 01:07:36.774: W/dalvikvm(821): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-17 01:07:36.774: I/Process(821): Sending signal. PID: 821 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's the error you see in logcat when the app crashes?

Answer (score 0):

A few runtime syntax error here:

class getIdOne

```
JSONObject jSon = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(personOne);
```

class getIdTwo

```
JSONObject jSon = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(personTwo);
```

class getFirstTitle

```
JSONObject jSon = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(creditURLOne);
```

class getSecondTitle

```
JSONObject jSon = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(creditURLTwo);
```

All json objects above are using `personOne`, `personTwo`, `creditURLOne` and `creidtURLTwo` while they are being declared `null`.